# List files restored from AWS Glacier to S3, time remaining?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

When you restore files from AWS Glacier, they go to a temporary location in S3 and remain there for the period specified in the restore request.

If that request was made by another tool, is there a way I can see the temporary storage location, and the time remaining in the temporary period?

`s3api list-objects` and `s3api list-objects-v2` just show the files still in `"StorageClass": "GLACIER"`, but I know the temporary files still exist because the other tool can now work on them at `STANDARD` speeds, rather than glacial ones.

While not urgent for me, this is surprising given you do get charged for S3 storage of the temporary objects - seems unfair if you can't delete a massive restore you made once you're finished with it!

Answer (score 2):

The temporary copy of the object is accessible by fetching the object as usual, using the same object key.  There isn't a separate location that is user-accessible.

If you make a `HEAD` request for the object, the response includes the `x-amz-restore` header:

```
x-amz-restore: ongoing-request="false", expiry-date="Fri, 23 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
```

The `expiry-date` is the date when the temporary copy will be removed, based on the number of days you specified when you initiated the restoration.

The `ongoing-request` value of `false` means the restoration from Glacier is complete, and the object is accessible, while `true` means the initial restoration operation is still in progress and the object is not yet ready for access.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html

It isn't possible to remove the temporary copy earlier than the number of days you specified, or to make it persist longer.  If you aren't sure how long you will need an object to be accessible, you can restore for only 1 day, and make a copy of the object and store it elsewhere when the restoration is complete.